# How can i remove Linux leftover partitions from my computer?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

### I used to have a Win10/Ubuntu Dual Boot, but now I want to remove Ubuntu.

I deleted the content of two partitions (one of each disk) I was certain they were a part of Ubuntu system, but now i'm left with lots of partitions and i don't know which of them I can delete. Please help!

---

Image of Disk Management: [Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWxAY.png)

---

cmd> DISKPART informations on my disks' partitions:

```
DISKPART> select disk 0

    DISKPART> list partition

      Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
      -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
      Partition 1    Recovery           499 MB  1024 KB
      Partition 2    System             100 MB   500 MB
      Partition 3    Reserved            16 MB   600 MB
      Partition 4    Primary            172 GB   616 MB
    * Partition 5    System             488 MB   173 GB
      Partition 7    Unknown             45 GB   173 GB
      Partition 8    Unknown           3907 MB   219 GB
      Partition 6    Recovery           548 MB   223 GB

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 1
    Type    : de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
    Hidden  : No
    Required: Yes
    Attrib  : 0X0000000000000001
    Offset in Bytes: 1048576

      Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
      ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    * Volume 4         Recuperação  NTFS   Partition    499 MB  Healthy    Hidden

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 2
    Type    : c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
    Hidden  : Yes
    Required: No
    Attrib  : 0000000000000000
    Offset in Bytes: 524288000

      Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
      ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    * Volume 1                      FAT32  Partition    100 MB  Healthy    System

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 3
    Type    : e3c9e316-0b5c-4db8-817d-f92df00215ae
    Hidden  : Yes
    Required: No
    Attrib  : 0000000000000000
    Offset in Bytes: 629145600

    There is no volume associated with this partition.

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 4
    Type    : ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
    Hidden  : No
    Required: No
    Attrib  : 0000000000000000
    Offset in Bytes: 645922816

      Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
      ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    * Volume 0     C   wOS          NTFS   Partition    172 GB  Healthy    Boot

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 5
    Type    : c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
    Hidden  : Yes
    Required: No
    Attrib  : 0000000000000000
    Offset in Bytes: 185792987136

      Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
      ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    * Volume 2                      FAT32  Partition    488 MB  Healthy    Hidden

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 7
    Type    : 0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
    Hidden  : Yes
    Required: No
    Attrib  : 0000000000000000
    Offset in Bytes: 186304692224

    There is no volume associated with this partition.

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 8
    Type    : 0657fd6d-a4ab-43c4-84e5-0933c84b4f4f
    Hidden  : Yes
    Required: No
    Attrib  : 0000000000000000
    Offset in Bytes: 235384340480

    There is no volume associated with this partition.

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 6
    Type    : de94bba4-06d1-4d40-a16a-bfd50179d6ac
    Hidden  : No
    Required: Yes
    Attrib  : 0X0000000000000001
    Offset in Bytes: 239481126912

      Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
      ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    * Volume 5                      NTFS   Partition    548 MB  Healthy    Hidden
```

```
DISKPART> select disk 1

    DISKPART> DISKPART> list partition

      Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
      -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
      Partition 1    Primary            390 GB  1024 KB
      Partition 2    Primary             75 GB   390 GB

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 1
    Type  : 07
    Hidden: No
    Active: Yes
    Offset in Bytes: 1048576

      Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
      ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
    * Volume 3     D   wData        NTFS   Partition    390 GB  Healthy

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    Partition 2
    Type  : 83
    Hidden: Yes
    Active: No
    Offset in Bytes: 419575103488

    There is no volume associated with this partition.
```

---

### EDIT: I found out that maybe this is also useful info

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /enum

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume2
path                    \EFI\MICROSOFT\BOOT\BOOTMGFW.EFI
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  pt-BR
inherit                 {globalsettings}
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {63c3c217-b2ef-11ea-875f-d55910ffad22}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {current}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \WINDOWS\system32\winload.efi
description             Windows 10
locale                  pt-BR
inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
recoverysequence        {63c3c219-b2ef-11ea-875f-d55910ffad22}
displaymessageoverride  Recovery
recoveryenabled         Yes
isolatedcontext         Yes
allowedinmemorysettings 0x15000075
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \WINDOWS
resumeobject            {63c3c217-b2ef-11ea-875f-d55910ffad22}
nx                      OptIn
bootmenupolicy          Standard
```

Comment: Please install and run [DriveLetterView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/drive_letter_view.html). Find under column "Device Path" the value `\Device\HarddiskVolume2` and report on the two matching values (in the same line) under the columns "Physical Drive Name" and "Volume Name".

Comment: unfortunately i can't seem to find Volume 2 in there. Only Volumes 4 and 9 as the image shows: https://imgur.com/a/XmgRzWU

Comment: You have multiples of everything. First step is to identify the useful partitions, starting with `HarddiskVolume2`. Download [dd for windows](http://www.chrysocome.net/dd) and run CMD as Admin - the command `dd --list` in its second part will translate it to something like `\\?\Device\Harddisk0\Partition2` which will identify it.